# SDIO MODE Control Register functionality in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, sd-card

I want to know which function/file implement SDIO Mode Control functionality (RWREQ , IOMOD, C52PUB, IOABT) in Linux Kernel ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the linux source code at location:

> LinuxKernelSrcCode/drivers/mmc/core/

Contains all the files related to sdio functionality like io, ioreq, ops...

For example:

> mmc_io_rw_direct()

is defined as a function in:
linux/drivers/mmc/core/sdio_ops.c, line 70

Are you looking for something specific???

Comment: I am looking for Read Wait(RWREQ),SDIO abort(IOABT) etc which are defined through SDIO_MODE Register in SDIO/MMC Specification. I am using TMIO host controller.  Thanks